# How to add this type of node description by Mermaid?

Tags: mermaid

This is a flowchart pattern that I really like to use and I currently use [drawio](https://app.diagrams.net/) to draw it:

[image]

Notice that there are two kinds of descriptions in the flow chart

- description1:How does A get to B
- description2:Some properties of B

I know Mermaid can implement the `description1` by:

```
graph TB
    A --->|"description1:<br>How does A get to B"| B
```

[image]

But `description2` is also very important to me, is there any way to achieve it?

---

## The current workaround:

I use the heading of subgraph instead of `description2`:

```
graph TB
    A --->|"description1:<br>How does A get to B"| B
    subgraph description2:<br>Some properties of B
    B
    end
```

[image]

But I have to say it's a very ugly temporary solution. So I ask here..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While some types of Mermaid diagrams explicitly support notes (e.g. [sequence diagrams](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/sequenceDiagram?id=notes)), flowcharts do not.

I believe the closest you're going to get is to connect `B` to itself with [an invisible link](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=an-invisisble-link) (`~~~`):

```
graph TB
    A --->|"description1:<br>How does A get to B"| B
    B ~~~|"description2:<br>Some properties of B"| B
```

[image: B connected to itself with a comment]

Comment: I have make a feature request suggestion [here](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/2712)